Mexican movie, comedy, released after 2014

Saw it on Netflix.
Set in modern times (After 2010).
Location: Mexico city.
Two best friends (a guy and a girl who are married) - the guy is actually gay and only got married to pretend in front of his parents move into a building, very rapidly, all the neighbors get together and start doing gatherings, one married woman falls in love with a married man from another floor. Someone gets killed and everyone start suspecting each other.
One of the actors is a attractive short-hair blond guy that use to star in one (telenovela) soap-opera very popular in 2014 or '15. I think there is also one of the actors from Amores perros or Matando Cabos.
The movie has a long title (4 or 5 words at least)


"long title" Indeed. ;) Sounds like I Don't Know Whether to Slit My Wrists or Leave Them Long (2013).

This comedy drama features two couples living in the same building, Lucas & Julia the catholics, Aaron & Nora the jewish and Lola the world traveler spanish. The story takes place at the arrival of a new renter the ex soccer player Felix; as soon as he's installed the neighbors gather for a dinner just to find out the problems between them; After this Lola reveals her couple problems, Julia and Aaron find themselves in love and Lucas tries to get Felix attention. The shocking sound of two gun shots sets all the neighbors in a suspicious crime scene.

It takes place in Mexico City, one of the couples is in a fake marriage to hide the man's homosexuality, and it stars Raul Mendez who was in Matando Cabos. Here's the trailer:



